# RecyclerView Not Loading all items

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter, listitem

I am populating Recycler View with a List of 7 string items but Recycler view only loads two of them

by the way my data is long text and it loads all items when text is short

this is my ContentAdapter.java

```
public class ContentAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ContentAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private List<String> mContent;

    ContentAdapter(Context context, List<String> Content) {
        this.mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        mContent = Content;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.rvcontent_item, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ContentAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        //loads only two times !?
        holder.txtContentPage.setText(mContent.get(position));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mContent.size(); // size is 7
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        TextView txtContent;
        ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            txtContent = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtContent);
        }
    }
}
```

rvcontent_item.xml

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtContent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

and Activity

```
        rvContents.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, RecyclerView.VERTICAL, false);
        rvContents.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        ContentAdapter contentAdapter = new ContentAdapter(this, Data); // Data has 7 items
        rvContents.setAdapter(contentAdapter);
```

and this is my layout activity xml

```
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/rvContentPage"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

Comment: please share your activity layout file code to check further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with

```
 <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/rvContentPage"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

The issue is

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/rvContentPage"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Here `android:layout_height="match_parent"` is a bug, since you are inside a scroll view your `recyclerview` should have height `wrap_content`. So that the parent will allow it to scroll.

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work my onBindViewHolder only runs two times

Comment: Please check with this, `@Override
    public int getItemCount() {
           Log.d("size",mContent.size()+"");  return mContent.size(); // size is 7
    }`

Comment: ensure the size is 7 or two

Comment: I'm sure the size is 7 i think it's about text size because I changed data text with a shorter one and it worked

Comment: Can you try with the new code, `androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView`

Comment: I hope you will give credit to the answer

Answer (score 0):

Try changing ConstraintLayout height match_parent instead of wrap_content.
and if persists, Remove scrollView from root because RecyclerView itself makes layout scrollable.